# git files permission on windows

Tags: php, windows, git, powershell

I have a php script that based on some conditions is going to remove a directory that is a repository downloaded using `git clone`. The script recursively finds files and directories and deletes them. It uses the `unlink` function to remove the files. This script works fine on mac and linux, however, on windows, i get some permission errors for files under `.git` directory that are created using `git clone` command.
To reproduce it:

```
git clone your-repository
```

Having this function:

```
<?php

function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        return unlink($dir);
    }

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        if (!deleteDirectory($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return rmdir($dir);
}
deleteDirectory('path-to-repository-directory');
```

if you try to run this script, you will get the error on windows.
When i try to delete the directory using file explorer, it works fine and i can delete the repository.

How can I fix the permission issue on windows?

PS: The code should work on GitHub action, which means I can not use file explorer.

Comment: Why is the `powershell` tag on this?

Comment: Windows has mandatory (as opposed to advisory) locking, and it's not uncommon for applications to lock files/dirs they are using. This prevents deletion giving a permission error. You can't get around it (without changing the app that has the lock), Windows does provide a mechanism to cause the file to be deleted later, but I don't remember what it is.

Comment: @lit it has the powershell tag because it is running on the powershell

Comment: I think this has something to do with how git works in windows. I can chmod the file's permission under the .git directory and delete them. But I don't understand why I need to do so.